# How can I access to the files of a game with data?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have a game called for example "Shadow Fight 2" and I like it soundtracks, so I want to have the songs but this game has data and the songs  didn't exist in the .apk file ( I opened it with an Archive Manager ) and it downloads from Internet, so the question is how can I access to the data it has downloaded? and by the way my phone is rooted.

Comment: Browse through **/data/data/<package_name>** or **/sdcard/Android/data/<package_name>** and see if there's something useful using a (Root) File Explorer. Or it maybe inside the **/sdcard/Android/obb/<package_name>/blah_blah vX.x.obb** file, if it's the case, you may need to unpack the .obb file and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure for apks with obb data but for apk files without obb associated just rename apk file with .zip extension and then extract res folder you will get all resources

Comment: OP already states he had explored the APK package, so this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: For shadow fight2

Comment: Here's the path for audio in shadow fight 2                       /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.nekki.shadowfight/cache/

Comment: Edit it into your existing answer - OP would gladly accept it if it works for him. Flag retracted for now.